# Displaying form errors with django-boostrap3

Tags: python, django, django-bootstrap3

I am developing a Web application with Django and django-bootstrap 3.

I have several forms which get validated and throw an error if something is wrong. However, I don't want django-bootstrap to show the alert messages in the dismissible red alert boxes. Error messages below input fields are sufficient.

How do I achieve this?

**Password change form example:**

```
<form class="allign-bottom" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    {% buttons %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            {% bootstrap_icon "glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" %}&nbsp; Update password
        </button>
    {% endbuttons %}
</form>
```

**Picture example:**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried disabling error in bootstrap 3 settings file? Try turning alert boxes off and see if that fixes the issue. should be a settings file for django-bootstrap-3 with this option.

Comment: Do you have `{% bootstrap_messages %}` at the top somewhere, maybe?

Comment: If the below answer helped you to resolve your issue, please mark it as accepted. It's a good practice in StackOverflow :)

Comment: What values should be specified in the bootstrap 3 settings file in order to disable the alert boxes? Could not find something in the documentation. Do I have to change the 'error_css_class' or something like 'form_renderers'?

Answer (score 0):

In order not to show the dismissable alert box at the top you should remove the

`{% bootstrap_messages %}`

template tag, that is placed somewhere in your HTML file.

This tag is responsible for showing any potential errors (actually it's just [Django messages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/messages/), formatted with the Bootstrap styling).

According to the source of [`{% bootstrap_messages %}`](https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3/blob/master/bootstrap3/templatetags/bootstrap3.py#L744), this template tag renders [`messages.html`](https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3/blob/master/bootstrap3/templates/bootstrap3/messages.html) which iterates over the messages and presents them (wraps each inside a `<div>` element).

Comment: Thanks for your input. However, no {% bootstrap_messages %} tags were used in my HTML files.

Comment: Are you sure? Maybe from a parent `{% block %}`?

Answer (score 0):

Is happening the same to me, so I went trough the code and this seems to be the default behavior at least at the latest versions of dango-bootstrap3

This is a known issue and it seems that will be fixed in next releases, there is an open issue and an already developed commit here:
https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3/issues/380

If you need this to work now, before the next version of the package is released, you can go to bootstrap3/renderers.py and arround line 227 (on version 8.2.3), you can change this:

```
return self.render_errors() + self.render_fields()
```

by:

```
return self.render_errors(type='non_fields') + self.render_fields()
```

Is not a good practise to manually change packages code, but if you need this to work now, it's a temporal solution until the new verison of the package it's released.
That should fix your issue.

Hope this helps!